# K8s cluster has kube-system pod limits that are excessively high

Tags: kubernetes, azure, kubectl, azure-kubernetes-service

Using AKS, the cluster has limits that are overcommitted due to `kube-system` pods having excessively high CPU/memory limits.

- `kube-system` pods like `coredns` or have a combined CPU limit of 300+%
- This is for a development environment. We have tried several different VM sizes like `Standard_B2ms` or `Standard_D2_v3` which do not seem to affect the `kube-system` pods limits/configurations.
- We cannot manually reduce the limits for these `kube-system` pods because it is subsequently reverted by AKS.
- Creating an additional node pool did not seem to solve the problem. Node taints were not respected.

[image: kubectl describe node]